# Characteristic function of a union

Tags: coq

In a constructive setting such as Coq's, I expect the proof of a disjunction `A \/ B` to be either a proof of `A`, or a proof of `B`. If I reformulate this on subsets of a type `X`, it says that if I have a proof that `x` is in `A union B`, then I either have a proof that `x` is in `A`, or a proof that `x` is in `B`. So I want to define the characteristic function of a union by case analysis,

```
Definition characteristicUnion (X : Type) (A B : X -> Prop)
           (x : X) (un : A x \/ B x) : nat.
```

It will be equal to 1 when `x` is in `A`, and to 0 when `x` is in `B`. However Coq does not let me `destruct un`, because "Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed for inductive definition or".

Is there another way in Coq to model subsets of type `X`, that would allow me to construct those characteristic functions on unions ? I do not need to extract programs, so I guess simply disabling the previous error on case analysis would work for me.

Mind that I do not want to model subsets as `A : X -> bool`. That would be unecessarily stronger : I do not need laws of excluded middle such as "either `x` is in `A` or `x` is not in `A`".

Comment: You can't compute relevant data (`nat`) from irrelevant `Prop`. Possible solutions are making the input relevant by using sum type instead of `\/`, or having the output type in `Prop`, or just using `\/` instead of a characteristic function.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @András Kovács, Coq prevents you from "extracting" computationally relevant information from types in Prop in order to allow some more advanced features to be used. There has been a lot of research on this topic, including recently Univalent Foundations / HoTT, but that would go beyond the scope of this question.

In your case you want indeed to use the type `{ A } + { B }` which will allow you to do what you want.

Comment: I need a definition of all subsets of a type `X`. Then given two subsets `A,B` according to this definition, I would get another subset with properties similar to `{A}+{B}`. But `{A}+{B}` itself is of type `Type`, not of type subset of `X`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the union of subsets should be a subset as well. We can do this by defining union as pointwise disjunction:

```
Definition subset (X : Type) : Type := X -> Prop.
Definition union {X : Type}(A B : subset X) : subset X := fun x => A x \/ B x.
```

Comment: That's almost what the `Ensemble` standard Coq lib does. I cannot define the characteristic functions of unions with this implementation, because case analysis on a `Prop` is refused in sort `Set`.